# How to sum the output of two commands and save it to a file?

Tags: shell-script, variable

I have two `kfsql` commands that get total count of users.

I need these two command outputs to be added up and printed to a `file.txt`

I tried:

```
var1= getdatabase1
var2= getdatabase2
echo "$var1"
echo "$var2"
var3=$((var1+var2)) or var3="$(($var1 + $var2))"
echo"$var3"
```

but the `var3` or `var1` and `var2` doesn't print the output of the command and total count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `getdatabase1` and `getdatabase2` are commands that print their counts to stdout you should be able to change your assignments to

```bash
var1=$(getdatabase1)
var2=$(getdatabase2)
var3=$((var1+var2))
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" > file.txt
```

the `$(...)` syntax runs the command between the parens and "returns" the `stdout` of that command, which we here save to our variables.  Without those the name of the command will be treated as a string itself and assigned to the variables, but it will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks Eric this worked beautifully.. you saved me Thank's a lot

Comment: @user163691 Glad to help.  Since it seems like this worked, you should consider accepting the answer (using the checkmark beside it) so others will both know the question has already been answered and in the future people will know which solution worked for you

Answer (score 0):

did you try to run them in a subshell as follows:

```
(getdatabase1; getdatabase2) > file.txt
```

if it is not workin, please elaborate the outtput you are getting or lack thereof.

Comment: That wouldn't get the sum of the counts into the file though

Comment: Hello MelBurslan i tried as you said but this didn't work.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Sorry.